# Android TrafficStats Api and network traffic history

Tags: android

Is there any way to get network traffic/data usage **history by day**? (I'm not interested in live tracking)

EXAMPLE: start app (APK), search some network traffic log 30 days back, and display some total bytes.

Class **TrafficStats** can return number of send/received bytes from the moment the device started, and that's it.

From **version 4.0**, Android has it's own build-in control/app named "Data usage" which does the exactly what I need, but what about versions before 4.0? Can I even access the data that "Data usage" control/app displays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to get network traffic/data usage history by day? (I'm not interested in live tracking)

Only by doing your own live tracking and recording the results yourself.

> From version 4.0, Android has it's own build-in control/app named "Data usage" which does the exactly what I need

That data is not available to us through the Android SDK.

Comment: I was afraid of that, after many hours of digging through Android SDK. Many thanks for quick answer/confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Since API level 23 (Marshmallow) it is also possible for developers to query for historical network usage data.

Check [NetworkStats.Bucket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStats.html)